# Turn off copy and copy/move (from workbook to workbook) without promting A formulas or sheet..?

Tags: excel, vba

I often get this and have to press enter like 1-5 mins to get rid of it
[image]

Is there any code to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'~~> Your Code

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Rout, I would like to implement it automatically so if there is copy or move sheet it will not prompt for thing like that.  I can do a macro copy and move sheet with your copy but then it require user interaction.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of a setting which can disable the above specific message without using VBA.

Comment: Made it as an answer. I truly appreciate all the help you provided, Siddharth Rout